# Problem related to the integration

Tags: real-analysis, limits, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Recently I read that $$\int_{-p^{2}}^{+p^{2}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^{2}-p^{2}}}dx$$ tends to a finite real number as $p \to 0$. Can anyone explain me why this is true?

Comment: Shouldn't the integral limits be $\pm p$?

Comment: No, they are $+p^{2}$ and $-p^{2}$.

Comment: But the radicand should be $p^2-x^2$, so $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{p^2-x^2}}\,dx$, right? It would still tend to $0$ if the radicand is negative, but through purely imaginary values.

Comment: http://univ.tifr.res.in/gs2014/Files/GS2012_QP_PHY_Y.pdf Answer of the problem B1 is option (b).

Comment: The integrand admits an elementary antiderivative, namely
$$
\log\left(\sqrt{x^2-p^2} + x\right)
$$

Comment: I need absolute value signs, and I'm not sure what's going on when $x$ is negative.

Comment: Working complex analytically and using the above formula I get $4\log(p) + 2\pi i$ which doesn't do what you want as $p \to 0$. Can someone fix my mistake?

Comment: @hunter I don't know what your mistake was, but you get $$\log \left(p^2 + i\sqrt{p^2-p^4}\right) - \log \left(-p^2 + i\sqrt{p^2-p^4}\right),$$ the real parts cancel since both arguments of the logarithm have the same absolute modulus ($\lvert p\rvert$), and the arguments are both very nearly $\pi/2$ (or $-\pi/2$ if you choose the other branch of the square root; add any multiple of $2\pi$ to both arguments when choosing a different branch of the logarithm), as, up to scaling, it's $\pm p + i$, so the difference tends to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

For $-1 < p < 1$, the integral

$$I(p) := \int_{-p^2}^{p^2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-p^2}}\,dx$$

has a purely imaginary value, since the radicand $x^2 - p^2$ is negative. Nevertheless, $\lim\limits_{p\to 0} I(p) = 0 \in \mathbb{R}$. Broadly, we can argue that the integrand has roughly the value $\pm \frac{i}{p}$, the sign depending on the chosen branch of the square root, and since the length of the interval of integration is $2p^2$, we have $I(p) \approx \pm 2ip \to 0$.

More precisely, we can substitute $x = py$, and obtain

$$I(p) = \int_{-\lvert p\rvert}^{\lvert p\rvert} \frac{1}{\sqrt{y^2-1}}\,dy.$$

In this form, it should be evident that $\lim\limits_{p\to 0} I(p) = 0$, since the integrand doesn't depend on $p$, and the interval of integration still shrinks to a single point.

Comment: I didn't understand why the integrand has roughly value $\pm \frac{i}{p}$.

Comment: For $x=0$, we have $\frac{1}{\sqrt{0^2-p^2}} = \pm i\frac{1}{p}$. For small $p$, the integrand doesn't change much as $$\sqrt{p^2-x^2} = \pm p \sqrt{1 - \frac{x^2}{p^2}} \approx \pm p \left(1 - \frac{x^2}{2p^2}\right) = \pm p \mp \frac{x^2}{2p}.$$ As $\lvert x\rvert \leqslant p^2$, we have $\lvert x^2\rvert \leqslant p^4$, and thus the difference to the value for $x = 0$ is $O(p^3)$, relative difference $O(p^2)$, which becomes $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-p^2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{0^2-p^2}} + O(p)$$.